# Finding nth element by class with Selenium Webdriver

Tags: ruby, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I'm new to Ruby and Selenium Webdriver and was wondering if anyone knew how to find the nth element when searching by class. I was able to find an answer for the java version but I'm not sure what the syntax is for Selenium.

here is the documentation I've been using: http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/RubyBindings

Here is my specific problem:
I am writing a program that crawls LinkedIn and views profiles found in the "People similar to ...." section. I found that the first similar person can be found with

```
element = browser.find_element(:class, "discovery-photo")
element.click
```

What I want to be able to do is to choose the element of the second (or third, or fourth) person in that least - so the third element with class = "discovery-photo". The way it is currently set-up it only returns the first one.

One more thing - I was able to find that the element number can be determined easily with `data-li-index` but I have no idea how I would use selenium webdriver to find that. I tried `find_element(:data-li-index, "1")` but that threw an error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the find_elements method, which will return all elements which match the particular class you specify.

```
browser.find_elements(:class, "discovery-photo")
```

This will return a list of elements which you can loop through.

Comment: So should I set an array equal to it?

array = browser.find_elements(:class, "discovery-photo")

And then select the correct element number in the array?

Comment: Yes. It would be an array of WebElements.

Comment: Really useful answer - this helped me out.

I used: array = browser.find_elements(:class, "discovery-photo")
array[9].click()